# How to remove wizard container title bar in swt/jface

Tags: java, swt, jface, wizard

I have created a wizard in swt/jface. and i would like to remove the wizard container bar. I checked the documentation of the wizard page but couldn't find anything. Is their is a way to do this.Here a pic to explain better

[image]

So i need to remove this red rectangaled part

Comment: I believe you're allowed to return null for the text to display in that area for a given page - does that accomplish what you want? (I'd put this as an answer if I had Eclipse in front of me to verify it with)

Comment: no, i have set the title as null but still seeing the container bar

Comment: So in that case it's just a big empty white box eh? That's pretty bad.  You could always try digging into the implementation of Wizard/WizardPage to see what draws that area and implement your own version - IWizard and IWizardPage are just interfaces after all...

Comment: I think you are right, the one thing i could do is to look into the implementation of the WizardPage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I'd try would be to try returning null from the methods that populate that area of the wizard UI.

If that doesn't work, you can always look into the Eclipse implementation of `Wizard` and `WizardPage` to see what draws that area and implement your own version that draws what you want - `IWizard` and `IWizardPage` are just interfaces after all.  I've done something similar (though this was a few years ago) for implementing a much more customized wizard that ended up containing a GEF editor inside it as well.